# Java Memory Model interaction of synchronization, volatile and (stamped) locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model

Is the `volatile` modifier required when working with locks to guarantee memory visibility?

Trying to fully understand concurrency, memory visibility and execution control I came across several sources saying that variables updated in `synchronized` blocks do not require the field to be `volatile` (mostly no sources given and actually one page saying synchronized methods and volatility fields need to be used in conjunction).

When approaching the [jls chapter 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/jls10.pdf) I found:

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action
>   happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

Is this the section which says that subsequent synchronized method calls guarding the same variable variable will ensure it to be visible to the second thread? If this is the case does the same hold true for locks since we can also guarantee an order?

On the other hand what happens when suddenly we have write locks allowing 2 threads to access the field. Does the entire construct collapse and threads are never guaranteed to updated their cache even in the event if the variable is unlocked?

In short code

```
int field; //volatile not needed because we have a definite happens-before relationship
Lock lock;

void update(){
    //No matter how many threads access this method they will always have 
    //the most up to date field value to work with.
    lock.lock()
    field *= 2;
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: `variables updated in synchronized blocks do not require the field to be volatile` this is correct.

Comment: Yes to the question immediately before this: `If this is the case does the same hold true for locks since we can also guarantee an order?` and yes to that also *if the documentation says that the lock has memory visibility side effects.*  Most of the locks from `java.util.concurrent` do have such a note in their API docs.

Comment: Your "short code" is still not thread-safe. because you used the lock to synchronize the update, but you fail to protect the instance variable `field` from other threads reading it and doing a compound action. To make your "short code" thread safe. You need to either volatile the instance fields or encapsulate them and synchronize the accessor methods.

Comment: A read-write lock only allows multiple readers. These readers still have a happens-before ordering relationship to the last update made by a writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API documentation for `Lock`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

> All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization
>   semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, as described in
>   Chapter 17 of The Java™ Language Specification:
>
> - A successful lock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Lock action.
> - A successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Unlock action.
>
> Unsuccessful locking and unlocking operations, and reentrant
>   locking/unlocking operations, do not require any memory
>   synchronization effects.

That's a little unclear imo but the gist of it is that yes, `Lock` is required to work the same way as a monitor (what the `synchronized` keyword does) and therefore your example does always make the most recent update of `field` visible without explicitly using the `volatile` keyword.

P.S. Get Brian Goetz's *Java Concurrency in Practice,* it explains all of this stuff in a lot more detail.  It's basically the bible of all things concurrency in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your time. If nothing tremendously new surfaces I'll accept your answer later today

Comment: No worries, take your time researching this out.

Answer (score 0):

> ...and actually one page saying synchronized methods and volatility fields need to be used in conjunction.

You can distill everything you need to know about memory visibility and `synchronized` blocks down to one simple rule. That is, whatever thread A does to shared variables and objects before it exits from a `synchronized (o) {...}` block is guaranteed to become visible to thread B by the time thread B enters a `synchronized (o) {...}` block *for the same object,* `o`.

And, as @markspace already said, any implementation of `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` is required to work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the volatile modifier required when working with locks to guarantee memory visibility?

`volatile` variable only guarantees memory visibility but not the atomicity. This is one of the main difference between `volatile` and the `synchronized` block in Java. So when you use `synchronized` blocks, variables do not have to be `volatile`. But If your variable is `volatile` and performing any compound actions on that variable, then you need to guard the update to the `volatile` variable with the lock.

> Is this the section which says that subsequent synchronized method calls guarding the same variable will ensure it to be visible to the second thread? If this is the case does the same hold true for locks since we can also guarantee an order?

Yes. Because locks will give you both visibility and atomicity.

> On the other hand what happens when suddenly we have write locks allowing 2 threads to access the field. Does the entire construct collapse and threads are never guaranteed to updated their cache even in the event if the variable is unlocked?

If you guarding the update to the variable on the same lock only one thread can work on that variable at any given time. So it guarantees consistency. But If you use different locks every time to guard that variable, then more than one thread will modify the variable state and can potentially make the variable state inconsistent. So, in this case, both visibility and atomicity are guaranteed but still, it can lead to inconsistency.